# Does Doxygen have a clobber-like parameter specification?

Tags: c++, doxygen

Consider the following function to remove duplicates from an array in linear running time

```
//! Removes duplicated integers
void remove_duplicate(
  vector<unsigned>&arr, //!< [in,out] Remove duplicates from this array
  vector<bool>&seen     //!< [???] All elements must be false and have at least as many elements as one plus the maximum number in \p max_int. After the function call finishes all elements are false.
)noexcept{
  {
    auto in=arr.begin(), out=arr.begin(), end = arr.end();
    while(in != end){
      if(!seen[*in]){
        *out = *in;
        ++out;
        seen[*in] = true;
      }
      ++in;
    }
    arr.erase(out, end);
  }
  {
    for(auto i=arr.begin(), end = arr.end(); i!=end; ++i)
      seen[*i] = false;
  }
}
```

The `seen` parameter exists for efficiency and exception safety reasons. Instead of passing it as parameter, one could have it as automatic variable within the function. However, this memory allocation could possibly throw. Further, if `removed_duplicate` is often called on the similar arrays, such as arrays of IDs from a known range, it can be a good idea to allocate the `seen` vector once per worker thread and then constantly reuse it.

I can mark parameter with Doxygen as "in", "out", or "in,out". `arr` clearly is an "in,out" parameter. The `seen` parameter fits in neither category. What do I put in there?

Comment: For doxygen this is, in my opinion, still an argument and should be [in,out].

Comment: An output parameter should convey some information computed inside of the function to the caller. The seen parameter conveys exactly zero information as it's state is required to be identical before and after the function call. At least by this definition, it is not an output parameter. Using a similar reasoning it is not an input parameter.

Comment: I don't see how it's not either. You're setting `seen` within the function and you assume `seen` has a certain size when the function is called. This makes it [in,out]

Comment: All modifications to seen are not observable by the caller. As such it is no output parameter as the motivation of an output parameter. However, as there is no answer yet, I believe that Doxygen has no such feature and I do agree that [in,out] comes closest.